# How to get the list of commits between two commits using Azdo rest API

Tags: azure, rest, devops, azure-rest-api

I tried using [commits rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
but it's listing the entire commit instead of the expected ones.

Used API like this: [https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxx/commits?api-version=7.0&searchCriteria.fromCommitId={fromcommit}&searchCriteria.toCommitId={tocommit}](https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxx/commits?api-version=7.0&searchCriteria.fromCommitId=%7Bfromcommit%7D&searchCriteria.toCommitId=%7Btocommit%7D)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using [commits rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) but it's listing the entire commit instead of the expected ones.

In order to get the list of commits between two commits, it is better to use **`searchCriteria.fromDate={searchCriteria.fromDate}&searchCriteria.toDate={searchCriteria.toDate}`**. It will provide you the commits as per the created date.

If you intend to use **`searchCriteria.fromCommitId={searchCriteria.fromCommitId}&searchCriteria.toCommitId={searchCriteria.toCommitId}`**, then it will provide you results either in alphabetical order if commit Ids are started with letters like `a*****1 to g*****0` or in numerical order if commit Ids are started with numbers like `0*****321 to 5******g23`.

I am using the below URL-

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.fromDate={searchCriteria.fromDate}&searchCriteria.toDate={searchCriteria.toDate}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

I am getting the expected results as shown below-

[image]

***References***-

[Rest-api-to-get-all-commit-info-between-base and target commit](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/get-commits-rest-api-to-get-all-commit-info-betwee/423538).